# Through a function passed in context, React state always has the initial value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm updating with functions that I pass from one component to its parent and then through context. I can set the state as I want but I can't access its data inside these functions. They show as the initial data. It's odd, I checked in React DevTools and the state is fine.

Here is a codeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-fog-2b5gm?file=/components/Provider.tsx:859-992
Link to the page : https://2b5gm.sse.codesandbox.io/

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import Provider from "./Provider";
import Consumer from "./Consumer";

export const context = createContext<AppContextType | undefined>(undefined);

type AppContextType = {
  actions: {
    addStrings?: (t: string[]) => void;
    logStrings?: () => void;
  };
};

const TestContainer = () => {
  const [actions, setActions] = useState<{
    addStrings?: (t: string[]) => void;
  }>({});

  return (
    <context.Provider
      value={{
        actions: actions
      }}
    >
      <Provider setActions={setActions} />
      <Consumer />
    </context.Provider>
  );
};

export default TestContainer;
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

type ProviderProps = {
  setActions: React.Dispatch<
    React.SetStateAction<{
      addStrings?: (t: string[]) => void;
      logStrings?: () => void;
    }>
  >;
};

const Provider = ({ setActions }: ProviderProps) => {
  const [textArray, setTextArray] = useState<string[]>([]);

  function addStrings(texts: string[]) {
    console.log("PREVIOUS LINES: ", textArray);
    console.log("NEW LINES:", [...textArray, ...texts]);
    setTextArray([...textArray, ...texts]);
  }

  function logStrings() {
    console.log("Strings : ", textArray);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("send functions to parent");
    setActions({ addStrings: addStrings, logStrings: logStrings });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect textArray changed to: ", textArray);
  }, [textArray]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Strings : </h1>
      {textArray.map((line, index) => (
        <p key={index}>{line}</p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Provider;
```

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { context } from "./TestContainer";

const Consumer = () => {
  const appContext = useContext(context);

  function onButtonAddClick() {
    if (appContext?.actions.addStrings)
      appContext.actions.addStrings(["test 1", "test 2", "test 3"]);
  }

  function onButtonLogClick() {
    if (appContext?.actions.logStrings) appContext.actions.logStrings();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onButtonAddClick}>Add strings</button>
      <button onClick={onButtonLogClick}>Log</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Consumer;
```

The data in question is the `textArray` state in the Provider component.
I'm calling the `addStrings` and the `LogStrings` methods from the `Consumer` component to control it.

Expected behavior:
`LogStrings` should log the actual value of the state. In this case : "test 1, test 2, test 3" but it always print the state's default value.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Which variable shows always the same data in which file? As far as I can see you also only change some state to contain **String 1 String 2 String 3**. So in which function can't you access data?

Comment: The state in question is "textArray" in the Provider component.
I'm using the "addStrings" and the "LogStrings" methods from the Consumer component. 
LogStrings should log the actual value of the state. In this case : "test 1, test 2, test 3" but it always print the state's default value.

Comment: Try adding `textArray` to the dependencies array of the `useEffect` that calls `setActions`.

Comment: @juliomalves It works ! I'm still trying to understand how but it works. Can you add it as an answer ? I will then mark my question as Resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the initial state getting logged is because `setActions` only gets called when `Provider` is first mounted, when `textArray` still has its initial value of empty array `[]`. That will be the value that `logStrings` will log, even if you change `textArray` externally.

To actually update `logStrings` with the new `textArray` value you pass in `addStrings(["test 1", "test 2", "test 3"])`, you'd need to call `setActions` again. This means adding `textArray` to the dependencies array of the `useEffect` that calls `setActions`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("send functions to parent");
    setActions({ addStrings: addStrings, logStrings: logStrings });
}, [textArray]);
```